# Criar trigger MySQL com condição de entrada

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, trigger

Olá, estou fazendo um sistema de cartão de crédito e criei uma coluna com os tipos de cartão usando ENUM('bronze','prata','ouro'), agora quero criar um trigger para que, quando o usuário entra com o tipo, o trigger bote automaticamente o limite, e condições de crédito em suas respectivas colunas. O que eu tentei até agora foi isso:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER 
`sistemacc`.`cartaodecredito_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `cartaodecredito` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.tipo = 'bronze' THEN 
    SET NEW.limite = 1000 AND NEW.condicoes='até 2x';
ELSEIF NEW.tipo = 'prata' THEN
    SET NEW.limite = 5000 AND NEW.condicoes ='até 8x';
ELSEIF NEW.tipo = 'ouro' THEN
    SET NEW.limite = 10000 AND NEW.condicoes = 'até 12x';
END if;
END
```

E o erro que o mysql retorna é esse :

> Error 1362: Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger SQL Statement:

Comment: Troca a trigger pra ` BEFORE INSERT `. Não da pra modificar a variável no after pq os dados já foram inseridos.

Comment: Tentei a lógica do BEFORE INSERT, o trigger até é criado, mas não funciona, sem motivo aparente

Comment: Nunca mexi com triggers em mysql. A sintaxe do SET está correta? desconfio que deveria ser `SET NEW.limite = 1000, NEW.condicoes='até 2x';` (com virgula ao invés de AND)